# What is the most appropriate way to persist configurations in Java?

Tags: java, file, configuration, persistence

I need persist some configurations of my sistem like options selected, user and password of database connection,  etc.

I heard of system.properties and text files, but I dont know what is best or more appropriate.

EDIT: Currently I'm using a properties file, but I don't know if is the better way.

Comment: I think that a file with the configurations be the best thing. How do I get this?

Comment: I'm using system properties, but I think that has muck work for each new property I add. I need something more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Commons Configuration
http://commons.apache.org/configuration/

You mention passwords ... hmmm should those be encrypted in some way?

This looks like it could handle that for you: http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html

Not sure about the use of these together ... you might have to pick one.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [Java Preferences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) which is built into the JRE. It will select the correct mechanism per environment (.config files in Linux and registry entries in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I got good mileage from adapting an extension of Java Preferences:
[Java Preferences to a File](http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/java-preferences-using-file-backing-store), from [davidc.net](http://www.davidc.net).  When using Java Preferences unmodified, the preferences are saved in an OS specific location and saving or recovering preferences for the system as opposed to the user could run into access privilege issues.

Answer (score -2):

Serialization is the easiest and best way.

Comment: Serialization is just a method of encoding data it has is not a means of storage.

Comment: Serialization is ok for short term things like transferring an object from one place to another or storing session data, but it's bad for longer term persistence because changes to classes can make them incompatible with the serialized data you've stored.